# Same statement gives an error when put in a for loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have a list data `storesNearby` that looks like this.

```
[ [...],[23349, 'storeName', "['0285434668']", 'open', [], 35.2132, 129.046],[...] ]
```

I passed this list in python to html. The code below works perfectly inside html`<script>` tag.

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{storesNearby[0][5]}}, lng: {{storesNearby[0][6]}} }, map: map});
```

I wanted to loop it, so this is what I did.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < parseInt({{count}}) ; i++) 
{ 
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{storesNearby[i][5]}}, lng: {{storesNearby[i][6]}} }, map: map});
}
```

Exactly copy-pasted, but with now index `i`, the statement suddenly starts giving "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element Undefined" error.

`count` is also a data passed from python storing the number of elements in `storesNearby`, and `count` is not a problem because when I put different statement inside the for loop, it loops as intended. `count` is 20 and `storeNearby[19][5]` works, so it isn't like `storeNearby` has less than 20 elements that's causing the problem as well.

This must be a simple error but I'm really clueless. 
Not sure if this can make a difference, but I use python/flask and html uses jinja2 template.

Comment: If you log `{{count}}` before your loop, what is the value?

Comment: I don't use Jinja2, but I suspect the problem is that `i` is a JavaScript variable, but the expression inside `{{...}}` is processed by Python.

Comment: Is the loop code in a `.html` file, or a `.js` file?

Comment: @JohnGordon The loop code is in .html and placed inside <script> tag

Comment: @Katie.Sun I understood your question as to check the value of {{count}} so put `alert('{{count}}')`, and it gives pop up that says 20 on it.

Comment: hmm. well then you shouldn't need the `parseInt`... javascript will do type conversion on its own. actually that could be the problem? perhaps give that a try

Comment: if that doesn't work, declare a var like `var tempCount = {{count}};` and use that as the limit for the for loop?

Comment: @Katie.Sun I hoped it had worked... :( but thanks for the idea.

Comment: dang. I'm out of ideas